# Dagger 2: Generated code doesnt compile

Tags: dagger-2

All,

i would appreciate some help with a situation i have where dagger generated code doesn't actually compile. We have a fairly elaborate setup with subcomponents as in the graph below, the components ending in S are subcomponents.

> A  - BS
>
> |
>
> CS - DS
>
> |
>
> ES - FS

All the subcomponents contain builder interfaces like so:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = BS_Module.class)
public interface BS {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    public interface Builder {
        Builder requestModule(BS module);

        BS build();
    }
}
```

In the module for A i have the following to get access to the other components:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Inject
public BS provideBS(Provider<BS.Builder> builder) {
    return builder.get().build();
}
```

The whole thing generates just fine, however the code that is generated for provideB' does not compile:

```
@Override
public BS provideBS() {
    return new BSImpl();
}
```

However BSImpl doest not have a zero args constructor, only:

```
private BSImpl(BSBuilder builder) {...}
```

Hope I made the situation somewhat clear, any help appreciated as i don't know how to get this resolved.

**SOLVED**

I got the dependency graph the wrong way around... A cannot directly depend on what BS provides, BS can only depend on what A provides.

Comment: Can you please post the compile error you are getting? Also, it would help readers with your question if you use standard Java class names.

Comment: @DavidRawson per your suggestion fixed the class names.  Error message is very simple: constructor BSImpl in class BSImpl cannot be applied to given types; required: BSBuilder, found: no arguments, reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

Comment: @DavidRawson per your 2nd comment. You cannot actually instantiate the builder as Dagger creates it as a private inner class

Comment: Generally if you have a no-arg subcomponent accessor on a Component, then Dagger will build it for you. Also, if you make a Builder instance available on a Component, Dagger will code-gen that too. The real question for me is why you would make an unqualified Component instance available through a `@Provides` method--I'm guessing Dagger is getting confused there. Will test it later.

Comment: @DavidRawson the main reason i have this is that i'm following the dagger website's example on subcomponents: [link](http://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html). The whole subcomponent setup is not working, The Provides in the subcomponents are not available in the A component. After a day and a half mucking about i either completely not understand Subcomponents, there is something else wrong in my code (for which i'm writing a clean room equivalent) or something is wrong in dagger ;)

Comment: To take a step back i recreated A - BS with a few test interface/class pairs [AB][Facade|Object]. You can find the  [source here](https://www.ocerta.com/owncloud/index.php/s/M7Tg0ruRFmRZasE). This doesn't pass the dagger compiler, which is where i went down this path. As a side note the dagger compiler (2.7) is very finicky: accidentally marking a subcomponent with \@Component throws an non-descript exception. Same for leaving out @Subcomponent.Builder, different but still non-descript exception. When i find some time i'll file the issues. All your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks that's much clearer - maybe consider putting the source inside the question. Sorry for the incorrect comments from before

Comment: @DavidRawson ultimately it was quite simple. I got the dependency graph the wrong way around... A cannot directly depend on what BS provides, BS can only depend on what A provides. The only thing that is left now is to figure out the scopes as i cannot get BS to provide singletons due to duplicate scope with A.

Comment: Do you want to add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in the comments:

> @DavidRawson ultimately it was quite simple. I got the dependency graph the wrong way around... A cannot directly depend on what BS provides, BS can only depend on what A provides. The only thing that is left now is to figure out the scopes as i cannot get BS to provide singletons due to duplicate scope with A. - [Michel Onstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6383762/michel-onstein)